# Powered USB Hub

Tags: usb, hardware

I have a N68KH 4 port USB 3 powered hub connected to my Raspberry Pi. The hub recognizes the Kingston Data Traveller but will not find the keyboard or mouse. ANy answers please?

Comment: What is the output of `lsusb`?

Comment: Oh, and connect your keyboard directly to the RPi ;D

Answer (score 1):

Here is two lists with supported USB hubs:

http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#Powered_USB_Hubs

http://elinux.org/RPi_Powered_USB_Hubs